# Add Byte Arrarys Using Recursion

Tags: c#

I need to write a function that will add two byte arrays using recursion. The test for this function is as follows :

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource("Add_Function")]
 public AddResult Add_WithRecursiveAlgorithm(byte[] a, byte[] b)
 {
   // Arrange

   // Act
   var result = AddRecursion(a, b);

   // Assert
   return new AddResult(a, b, result);
  }
```

For example:

```
Input : { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }
Result: {2,2,2}

Input : { 1, 1, 255 }, {0, 0, 1 }
Result: {1,2,0}
```

The general rules are as follows:

•   Assume inputs a & b are never null and will always be the same length.

•   The algorithm should be non-destructive to the inputs.

•   The algorithm should be able to handle large input lengths, >1000, but the input will never be large enough to cause a stack overflow.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Well, where is your function that you need to write? Where are you stuck? How did this question get an upvote??

Comment: Well, that's all very nice and all, but what have you tried? You have too much reputation to not be aware of the fact that so is not a free code writing service.

Comment: It's not code writing service so you need to provide your current attempt

Comment: This is not a place where people do your homework for you.

Comment: I think you are looking at the assignment the wrong way. I think the recursive call should occur when the method is being called with a result simular to the second output. Where the later byte is greater then 255 so the previous byte has to be increased. Just my 5 cents though(Thinking this because the current use of recursion makes no sense at all)

Comment: Why would you use recursion for this?

Comment: btw, what should be the result of the following inputs? `{250, 50, 130}, {4, 200, 180}`?

Comment: Also you have more rules than you have listed if your examples are anything to go by. For example it looks like you have a rule to do with carrying when the result is > 255 which you have not mentioned at all but your second example seems to suggest exists. If you want useful answers you will need to provide a full spec that matches the examples you give.

Answer (score 0):

```
public object[] Add_Function()
{
    return new object[]
    {
        new object[]
        {
            new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new byte[] { 2, 2, 2 }
        },
        new object[]
        {
            new byte[] { 1, 1, 255 }, new byte[] { 0, 0, 1 }, new byte[] { 1, 2, 0 }
        }
    };
}

[TestCaseSource("Add_Function")]
public void Add(byte[] a, byte[] b, byte[] expected)
{
    // arrange
    int len = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
    Array.Resize(ref a, len);
    Array.Resize(ref b, len);
    byte[] result = new byte[len];

    //act
    DoAdd(a, b, result, 0, len - 1);

    //assert
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}

private void DoAdd(byte[] a, byte[] b, byte[] result, int broughtForward, int index)
{
    int carriedForward = (a[index] + b[index] + broughtForward) / (byte.MaxValue + 1);
    result[index] =(byte)((a[index] + b[index] + broughtForward) % (byte.MaxValue + 1));
    if (index > 0)
    {
        DoAdd(a,b,result, carriedForward, index-1);
    }
}
```